# How to declare and use an array of dictionaries from Python in Java and filter them?

Tags: java, python, dictionary

I'd like to understand how dictionaries work in Java,

I know that I can do something like

```
Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
map.put("dog", "type of animal");
System.out.`println`(map.get("dog"));
```

But I want to insert something that similar to what we do in python

```
T= []

value= {'name': 'someone', 'age': 13, 'tall': 1.55}
```

and I can add value to T, so I can filter them later by field ? Is this doable ?

**UPDATE**

In python, I add a list of dict to a list, to easily filter them.

```
T= []
a= {'name': 'someone', 'age': 13, 'tall': 1.55}
b= {'name': 'Jack', 'age': 14, 'tall': 1.39}

T.append(a)
T.append(b)
```

The result:

```
T= [ {'name': 'someone', 'age': 13, 'tall': 1.55}, {'name': 'Jack', 'age': 14, 'tall': 1.39}]
```

I would like to know what is the equivalent structure of these datastructure in python. How can I declare varibale like a, and b ?

```
filtered_T = [v for v in T if v['name'=='someone']]
```

this will give

```
T= [ {'name': 'someone', 'age': 13, 'tall': 1.55}
```

Comment: You need to make an array of Maps.

Comment: You can use `List<Map<String, String>>`.

Comment: can you show that in an example ?

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza How about using a struct and adding it to SortedList ?

Comment: There aren't `struct`s in Java. There's no `SortedList` in Java SE (there's [`SortedList`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/collections/transformation/SortedList.html) but belongs to Java FX).

Comment: @Luiggi Mendoza Can you show a quick example on how to use/filter ?

Comment: It will be better if you post what you want/need to achieve.

Comment: You would typically create a class for that with the appropriate attributes, and then build a `List<MyClass>`. Filtering can be pretty easy if you use Java 8.

Comment: @Luiggi Mendoza Check UPDATE, I tried to do what I wanted to understnad in python, can you help explaining

Comment: Ok, now your question is clear and more concise, thus answerable.

Comment: @Luiggi Mendoza what I ended-up doing is creating an interface and casting some datastructures.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Java, you would typically create a class for this.

```
class Person {
    private final String name;
    private final int age;
    private final double height;

    //constructors, etc.
}
```

Then you would have a data-structure that holds the elements. A `List<Person>` could perfectly do the job here.

```
Person p1 = new Person("someone", 13, 1.55);
Person p2 = new Person("Jack", 14, 1.39);

List<Person> personsList = Arrays.asList(p1, p2);
```

The list comprehension you have to filter your elements would be written as (with Java 8):

```
personsList = personsList.stream()
                         .filter(p -> p.getName().equals("someone"))
                         .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

or

```
personsList.removeIf(p -> !p.getName().equals("someone"));
```

Basically, you get the stream from the original list, filter the person instances that have "someone" as their name, and collect the filtered elements into a list, that you assign back to the variable `personsList`.

The second approach removes the element in place in the list. Of course it only works if the implementation supports removal of elements.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.ur help is appreicated

Comment: Can you help with this ? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33900057/how-can-i-group-values-of-list-in-java-using-lambda-like-we-do-in-python