# How can I group values of List in Java using Lambda like we do in python

Tags: java, python, lambda

I want to group values of a map based on the key. Let's say

```
Map<String,Integer> map1 = new TreeMap<String,Integer>();
map1.put("D", 3);
map1.put("B", 2);
map1.put("C", 1);

Map<String,Integer> map2 = new TreeMap<String,Integer>();
map2.put("A", 13);
map2.put("B", 22);
map2.put("C", 12);

Map<String,Integer> map3 = new TreeMap<String,Integer>();
map3.put("A", 33);
map3.put("B", 32);
map3.put("C", 32);

Map<Integer,Map<String,Integer>> map = new HashMap <Integer,Map<String,Integer>>();

map.put(1,map1);
map.put( 2, map2);
map.put(3, map3);
System.out.println(map);
```

I want to group values in the map based on the keys: Output should be `["A","B","C"]:[2,3], ["D","B","C"]:[1]`

So what I have done:

```
Map<List<String>, List<Integer>> newMap = new HashMap<List<String>, List<Integer>>();

for (Integer item : map) {
    Map<String,Integer> currentValue = map.get(item);
    List<String> oldItemKeySet = newMap.get(currentValue.keySet());
    newMap.put(currentValue.keySet(), (oldItemKeySet == null) ? 1 : oldItemKeySet.put());
}
```

But it doesn't work out, can anyone help here.

PS: In Python, these things can be done with `itertools.groupby` or `reduce`, but i am still don't knoww how to do it perfectly in Java

Comment: Yes, I am using JAVA8. I still don't know how to do things with lambda

Answer (score 0):

If I understand well, you want to group the identical key set of the maps you added in the last map associated with the original key.

```
import static java.util.stream.Collectors.groupingBy;
import static java.util.stream.Collectors.mapping;
import static java.util.stream.Collectors.toList;

...

Map<Set<String>, List<Integer>> newMap = 
    map.entrySet()
       .stream()
       .collect(groupingBy(e -> e.getValue().keySet(), 
                           mapping(Map.Entry::getKey, toList())));
```

From the last map, you get the stream of entries (which is a `Stream<Entry<Integer, Map<String, Integer>>`). There you group the entries by the key set of their map's values.

Then you map the values of the resulting map using a downstream collector, which collects the keys of the original entries in a `List<Integer>`.

Output:

```
{[A, B, C]=[2, 3], [B, C, D]=[1]}
```